# ffmpeg related issue

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using the following command for video conversion using `ffmpeg` and it is working fine:

```
ffmpeg -i 'in.wmv'  -s 1280x720 -b 256 -ar 44100 -ab 64k -ac 2  'output.mp4'
```

However, when I am playing the converted file into the totem player then in properties section **audio bitrate** and **video bitrate** are being displayed as **N/A**.  The **audio bitrate** and **video bitrate** must be 256 and 64k respectively.

Comment: You may want to consider asking your question on http://superuser.com

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your *-b* option is 256. *-b* is used to set the **video** bitrate. you should set it to 64k if that's what you want. The audio bitrate is set with *-ab*, which you are setting to 64k...

And, btw, *-ar* defaults to 44100 and *-ab* defaults to 64k so you don't need to pass those arguments if you don't want to.